# How to post an array of JSON objects to a Struts2 action using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, struts2

Using Struts2.
In my Action I have a `List<Person> persons;`

In javascript, I have this function:

```
function mytestfunction() {
    var url = "MyAction_mytestfunction.action";
    var params = {};
    var arr = [];
    var p1 = { "firstname" : "John", "lastname" : "Doe"};
    var p2 = { "firstname" : "Rob", "lastname" : "Smith"};
    arr.push(p1); arr.push(p2);
    params["persons"] = arr;
    $.post(url, params, function(data) {
        console.log("done");
    });
}
```

Problem is, the post() never reaches the action. There are no errors in the logs, nothing.

This all changes if instead of posting objects I post primitives. So when I have a `List<Integer> nums` in the Action and `params["nums"] = [1,2,3];` in javascript, everything is posted fine.

So, is there a way to post JSON objects to a Struts2 action via javascript/jquery?

I should mention that I'm using the struts-jquery plugin, not dojo.

Comment: why don't you use S2 Json plugin which will take care of sending and receiving JSON data between UI and Action classes?

Comment: How would I use the JSON plugin to send to the action using the struts-jquery plugin? The examples I've seen use dojo, not jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about struts, but this is how I POST objects with json:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(SOME_JAVASCRIPT_OBJECT),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    // etc: etc
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try as following example:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "Post",
    url: "action_name",    //you can pass through querystring like actionname?paramname=value
    data : {
           //here comes your param or array 
        },
    dataType:"json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
});
```

If you want to pass through querystring type must be GET